# Regex|Ignore second word(s) of string if it contains certain words

Tags: c#, regex

```
/((?:(?:is|will) (?!is))[^<?]+)/i
```

Test sentences:

- text can be infront, Will is a good guy?
- same here. Will you be able to help me?

I dont want it to match the first sentence and I want it to match the second.(which it does atm)

I am trying to learn how I can return the whole regex as false if the word after "is|will" is "is", but it keeps matching and eventually finds a match in example number one. I am kind of new to regex, so all help is appreciated.

This is what the match looks like:

[image: what the match looks like]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be easier for people to answer your question if you could list your test cases along with the expected result for each. I know that you described the logic in the question, but it's easier for some of us to see examples and expected results.

Comment: Maybe just `@"(?i)\b(?:is|will)\b(?\s+is\b)[^>?]*"`?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression seems fine, but you need to [anchor it](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) so that it starts matching from the beginning of the text. You can use `^` at the start of the regex.

```
/^((?:(?:is|will) (?!is))[^<?]+)/i
```

Without the anchor, the regex engine tries to find a match anywhere in the string. In the case of the first sentence, it can match the word `is` as the first word in the expression, and then the rest of the expression matches.

Comment: What if there is some text before the anchor? I am using it on a discord bot, so a posibility would be a tag infront "@user, will..." i would want it to return the entire sentence, but ignore it if the word after 'will' is 'if'

Comment: @JoacimK.Solbakken: The requirement you mentioned in your question's title mentions the _second_ word. Regex is good for matching against positive expectations. With negative expectations, you have to be more specific. Your requirements are not entirely clear to me at this point, but it may not be possible to do what you want via regex only.